# How to add a link with crow's foot erd notation in jointjs

Tags: jointjs

Is there any way to have a link in crow's foot notation with JointJS?

If yes, what would be the code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make crow feet notation in jointjs. 
Need to edit in shapes, 
Code for one-to-many is

```js
case '1 optional-N optional':
    attrs = {
             '.marker-source': {
               d: 'M 10 0 L 10 20 L 10 10 L 0 10 L 14 10 a 5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a 5,5 0 1,0 -10,0',
               fill: '#FFFFFF'
              },
             '.marker-target': {
               d: "M 0 0 L 10 10 L 0 10 L 10 10 L 0 20 L 10 10 a 5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a 5,5 0 1,0 -10,0",
               fill: '#FFFFFF'
              }
    };
break;
```

Comment: Thirumal, Thanks for the answer. When I tried to run the code snippet, it's expired. can you make it live again?