# Jointjs how to make link with crow's foot all three fingers connect to the box

Tags: jointjs

This is a follow up to my previous question [How to add a link with crow's foot erd notation in jointjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518524/how-to-add-a-link-with-crows-foot-erd-notation-in-jointjs)

[image]

Here is the code with the help of Thirumal.

```
  var lnk = createLink(parent, child).set(createLabel('0,N     1,1')); 
  lnk.attr({'.connection-wrap': { text: "FK columns: "+row.cols.replace(",",", ") }     })
     .attr({'.marker-source': { d: 'M 10 0 L 10 20         L 10 10 L  0 10 L 10 10 a 5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a 5,5 0 1,0 -10,0', fill: '#FFFFFF'}   })
     .attr({'.marker-target': { d: "M  0 0 L 10 10 L  0 10 L 10 10 L  0 20 L 10 10 a 5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a 5,5 0 1,0 -10,0", fill: '#FFFFFF'}   });
```

The crow's feet looks somewhat disconnected from the gray rectangle. How can I make the three fingers all connected to the target gray rectangle dynamically no matter where I drag the target?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @Shawn, did you solve it?